# How to create Vector Icon from .png Icon in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, png, vector-icons

I want to create vector icon from .png image in my drawable folder so how can I create this?

Comment: You can convert .svg to vector drawable using this link http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/

I am not sure if it is possible to create vector icon from .png in android studio

Answer (score 4):

You can not do this with Android Studio, But you can do this with some tools or with some website. eg: https://vectormagic.com/  The cost at this time is $9.95 per month.

Also available is Inkscape, an open source project, which runs on Mac, Linux, and Windows: https://inkscape.org/

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use vectr.com to create a vector image online

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31422371)